# Laravel 4 - Local to Staging 404 issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes, staging

I hope that this isn't too broad a question but I have been developing a site locally for a month or so and am ready to put it up on my staging server. The deployment all went smoothly after a little issue installing Mcrypt but all is good now, except for in my staging environment I get a 404 on every route.

They way my application is structured is I have folder in app that contains each of my modules, each module (Users, Auth, Teams etc.) each have their own routes.php file aswell as controllers/models/repositories etc.

If I access the site using say /login I recieve a 404, however, If i was to quickly create that route in the main routes.php file in app/ it works which is leading me to believe that for some reason the server isn't loading the individual modules files.

Can you give me a hand narrowing it down, what sort things should I look at etc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get a 404 from Laravel or your server?

Comment: It's from Laravel, after about 2.5 hours I think I have narrowed down the issue, the modules are loading but there does seem to be a problem with the path each modules route file. Investigating further this morning ...

Comment: Maybe a trailing slash issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found out the issue.

For some reason my local (homestead) environment wasn't too bothered about case sensitivity, however, my staging server was. A few tweaks and I am up and running, cheers for the ideas though :)